# Changing a csv file to an excel file using pandas and adding a row at the top of the excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I have a pandas dataframe that is stored in a csv file and i am trying to take this csv file and turn it into and excel file, this i have done. However, the csv file doesn't have any column name (a top row), i would like to add this to by excel file.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'Y:\DAILY.csv', sep=';')
df.to_excel(r"Y:\DAILYF.xlsx", startrow=1)
```

I thought i could set startrow to 1 and then define the top row using xlsxwriter:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r"Y:\DAILYF.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(0, 0, 1234)    
workbook.close()
```

This is clearly just an example but this overwrites the information that i retrieved from the csv file which is undesirable. Ideally just a simple definition of the top row whilst keeping the csv file information as it was in the excel file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the header names when opening the file in pandas like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Y:\DAILY.csv', 
                 sep=';',
                 names=["Col_name_a", "Col_name_b", "Col_name_c"])
```

And then you can write it to an excel file - excel can also natively open CSV files too.

Comment: I suppose OP wants to have custom header, not column names.

Comment: No problem! If it worked, would you mind marking the answer as accepted then? Thanks!